# Cucumber step with multiple DataTables

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

How can I write a Cucumber step that has two DataTables?

How it should be written in the feature file?

For example , a step to drag a row from one table to second table:

```
When I drag a row from  
   | column_table1 |   
   | object1       |  
to   
   | column_table2 |   
   | object2       |
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Do you want info about how it should look in the .feature file, or the _step.java file, or both?

Comment: I meant, how it should be written in the feature file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no special syntax to add a second table. Just add it.

```
When I drag a row from:
| column_table1 |   
| object1       |  
And I drop it at:
| column_table2 |   
| object2       |
```

AFAIK, you can only have one table per step, but you can have as many steps with tables as you want. One way I approach the problem is storing the tables in a variable to often reference in a third step:

```
Given I have a source row from:
<table>
And I have a destination row at:
<table>
When I drag from the source row and drop at the destimation row
Then .....
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this is nice workaround. Still it was nice if there was a way to rinclude two DataTables in a step with a separator between them.

Comment: You could "fake" it by adding another column to hold the "table" name. But I really think that would be more effort than it's worth as you'd have to deconstruct the one table into the mutliple tables you desired.